# Error in if (delta < tol) break : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

```r
library("mvmeta")
library("dosresmeta")
lin <- dosresmeta(formula = logHR ~ dose, id = study, 
                  type = type, se = se, cases = cases, 
                  n = personyear, data = breast)
```

> Error in if (delta < tol) break : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> Otherwise: Warning message:
> In log(Ax[v != 0]) : NaNs generated

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

At least one of your values in `breast$cases` is a negative number. You can check this with:

```r
table(breast$cases < 0, useNA = "always")
```

**Rationale**

The `dosresmeta` function will call the `covar.logrr` function, which will call the `grl` function (try running `traceback()` after getting the error). The essential code in `grl` is:

```r
cases <- eval(mf.cases, data, enclos = sys.frame(sys.parent()))
Ax <- Axp <- cases
y[v!=0] + log(A0) + log(n[v!=0]) - log(Ax[v!=0]) - log(n[v==0])
```

Essentially, the function takes the `cases` column, assigns it to `Ax`, and then tries to run `log(Ax[v!=0])` (see your error).

It is known that taking the log of a negative number will yield a `NaN`, as stated by your error:

```r
log(-1)
# [1] NaN
# Warning message:
# In log(-1) : NaNs produced
```

Therefore, I think that your `cases` columns contains non-positive numbers.